# Set a time for when object to be posted in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to implement a feature where you can select a date for when a post can go public in the Django admin. Is there a way we can set this in Django? What's the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking along the wrong lines. Instead of having a status flag which is flipped at a certain time, which would involve cron jobs, you only need a single publish_at field - then your front end can show all the posts with publish_at before now.